# Ajax modal popup extender can't show image

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, imagebutton

I have problem about viewing image from imagebutton on asp.net gridview

my image button

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cover Depan" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="cover1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("cover1") %>' CommandArgument='<%# Eval("cover1") %>' OnClick="ImagePopUp" Width="100" Height="100" />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

my popup extender

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeImg" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnDummyc1"
   PopupControlID="pnlImg" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
   DropShadow="true" Enabled="true" CancelControlID="btnCancel">
</ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

my panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlImg" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup">
      <asp:Image ID="imgBig" runat="server" Height="100" Width="100"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

and my void

```
protected void ImagePopUp(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        string ImageName = ((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument;
        imgBig.ImageUrl = Server.MapPath("..") + "/" + ImageName;
        mpeImg.Show(); 
    }
```

and my dummy button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDummyc1" runat="server" style="display:none"/>
```

the result i already have is a blank image

i don't know what's wrong with my code, please help me if you know wrong of my code

Answer (score 0):

```
Server.MapPath("..") + "/" + ImageName;
```

This Path is incorrect i think, do one think
go to your browser and right click on blank image and select "Inspect Element" option.

it will show you html code there you can check your image url it is correct or not.

Comment: so, what is the correct code to show an image that upload on folder cover and path is "../cover/image.jpg"? do you have any suggestion please

Comment: from inspect element i can't find the path of my image i just find <img id="Isi_imgBig" style="height:100px;width:100px;">, but from breakpoint i got that ImgBig.ImageUrl have value "C:\\Users\\Kukuh Wicaksono\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\SIP\\SIP\\User/~//cover//gambar3.jpg"

Comment: yes it's wrong... set this if url in Database like "/cover/image.jpg"-----> Image1.ImageUrl = "~/"+ImageName;

Comment: oh sorry i forgot, the main problem is not about the correct path, but i put the image button on asp gridview, i try to put it not on gridview then it's work, but even i put it on asp gridview it can't work